# Quelques revues françaises comme The Economist ?

Tags: ressources, apprentissage

Je suis de niveau B1 maintenant. Pour ceux qui ne parlent pas Anglais comme langue maternelle, *The Economist* est un magazine que lisent beaucoup ceux qui préparent le TOEFL ou IELTS. Y a-t-il un équivalent de ce genre de matériel en français pour s'entraîner ? Une recommandation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'équivalent de *The Economist* tant par la teneur et le sérieux du contenu que par l'utilisation par les enseignants et étudiants dans les cours de FLE (Français Langue Étrangère) est *[Le Monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/)*. Les deux sont utilisés plutôt à partir du niveau B2-C1.

*Le Monde* est un quotidien, et non un hebdomadaire comme *The Economist*. L'hebdomadaire *Courrier international* peut aussi être recommandé pour la qualité de la langue mais les informations sont des [reprises de la presse internationale](http://www.courrierinternational.com/notule-source) et pas des articles de fond et des analyses originales comme en contiennent *The Economist* et  *Le Monde*.